# Override / Edit the get / set functions of a Property

Tags: python, properties

How would I dynamically edit the get/set functions of a custom property?

```py
from typing import Callable
import bpy
from bpy.props import StringProperty, PointerProperty


class MyPropertyGroup(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):

    def getter(self):
        return self.get("name", str(self))

    def setter(self, new_name: str):
        self["name"] = new_name

    name: StringProperty(name="Name", get=getter, set=setter)

def other_setter(target, new_name: str):
    target["name"] = new_name + "foo"

def change_setter(property: bpy.types.Property, setter_func: Callable):
    # TODO
    pass

bpy.utils.register_class(MyPropertyGroup)
bpy.types.Scene.prop_group = PointerProperty(type=MyPropertyGroup)

prop_group = bpy.data.scenes[0].prop_group
name_prop = prop_group.bl_rna.properties.get('name')
change_setter(name_prop, other_setter)
prop_group.name = "bar"
print(prop_group.name)
assert prop_group.name == "barfoo"
```

Is it also possible to delete the setter function entirely in order to toggle the property attribute as "readonly"?

```py
def delete_setter(property: bpy.types.Property):
    # TODO
    pass

delete_setter(name_prop)
prop_group.name = "babar"
# AttributeError: bpy_struct: attribute "name" from "MyPropertyGroup" is read-only
```

Note that [`bpy.ops.wm.properties_edit()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.properties_edit) does not have fields for changing the get/set functions, but it does mention something for custom properties

> **eval_string** *(string, (optional, never None))* – Value, Python value for unsupported custom property types